# Version Control and deployment with Setup menu and Dev console

Tags: deployment, developer-console, setup, versioning, version-control

If i choose to do customization and coding through Setup menu and Developer console in my dev sandbox without using Force.com IDE plugin with eclipse, what process should i follow to use version control and deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m not sure why you are not going to use IDE..

but to answer your question one option is to

- setup [Force Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) (Ant) scripts to **retrieve** the
  metadata components you are interested in from the **source sandbox** on a scheduled job and push it to Git / SVN
- have Jenkins / Teamcity / Bamboo to pick up the changes from your Git / SVN and again use Migration Tool scripts to **deploy** the changes in the commit to your **target sandbox**

this is just one way but there are different possibilities in setting up Source Control, Auto builds & deploy, Running tests, overall CI setup..

There are lot of articles around this which are very useful..

[Source Control System and Deployment Tools](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/index_Left.htm#CSHID=lifecycle_adv_example_company.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Flifecycle_adv_example_company.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

[Cruise Controls for Force.com CI](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Continuous_Integration_Cruise_Control_and_Force_Com)

[Configuring Migration Tool](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/Content/lifecycle_adv_ant_tool_configuration.htm#ant_tool_package_xml)

Comment: working with IDE requires working with xml files. Lots of things can be done easily with clicks on a friendly UI through options in setup menu / console. isnt it ? Can we have setup menu similar wizards in Force.com IDE ?

Comment: for the first bullet point in your answer, is it better to use one sandbox per developer or should all use same sandbox ?

Comment: there's no direct answer ! its up to the team to come up with an approach that will work for them. I have seen some people using one per developer, but some teams using one per project and one for BAU work